# How to use post method in ruby?

Tags: html, ruby, json

I have a form that contains text boxes which gets the values of name and title. And a submit button is present. I want to get the values of the text boxes and send it in the format shown below to an api.

```
    {  
     "entry":
       { 
        "name":"api-workspace",
        "title":"API Workspace"
       }
    }
```

How can i do it using ruby?
please give me some sample codes if available.

Comment: Is it is possible to do those i have mentioned above without rails?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. So, are you or are you not using rails?

Comment: What are you using then?

Comment: This is painful. Please update your answer to show people what you're using, what you're trying to do exactly, and what you've tried. No one can help you otherwise

Answer (score 0):

The values are passed to your controller in the `params` hash. Assuming your textfields' names are `name` and `title` this should work:

```
json = { entry: { name: params[:name], title: params[:title] } }.to_json

puts json # => {"entry":{"name":"api-workspace","title":"API Workspace"}}
```